# Is better optimize the image in server or in local?

Tags: android, mysql

So i´m creating a app in Android which stores images in a external server. I want to know where is better to make the optimization of the image file, in server, or give the non-optimize image to local and then optimize inside the app. Im using mysql for store the images, but if its better to use sqlite server i will change it. Thanks.

Comment: Optimize on the server, use a caching mechanism at client end. Check Universal Image Loader on Github.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is create an application on your server exposed through an API with query parameters to specify image sizes + caching mechanism.

For example:

www.mywebsite.com/imageloader/file-identifier?width=50&height=50&format=png

then implement a caching mechanism take a look at (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ha-memcached.html) for mysql on the server for this image using these parameters so the application can quickly return this file each time and not require too much work from the application. This will allow you to request multiple images at specific sizes when you need them for example only as a thumbnail... Or a full Gallery image which can be something much larger.

Additionally you will want to use an Image Library and there are certainly quite a few for Android (to name a few):

**Picasso** from Square http://square.github.io/picasso/

**Fresco** from Facebook https://github.com/facebook/fresco

**Ion** from this Github https://github.com/koush/ion

These can all help you format your images and cache them locally and even downsize the images as necessary.